# Undefined Variable in template-contact.php on line 92

Tags: variables, undefined

I have a wordpress website, and I am getting an error message above the form on my contact page.

Error message reads:

Notice: Undefined variable: success in /home/crea6303/public_html/westafricanplumbing.com/wp-content/themes/waseps-custom/template-contact.php on line 92

template-contact.php code is:

```
<?php if($success) {
echo "
<div class=\"info-message\" style=\"background-color: #75a226;\">
<a href=\"#\" class=\"close-info\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i></a>
<p><strong>".__('Success:', DAT_NAME)."</strong>".__('The Message has been sent', DAT_NAME)."</p>
</div>";
} ?>
```

I don't have a clue how to fix this...can anyone help?

Thank you kindly
Ferg

Comment: Maybe You want `if (!empty($success)) {`, if You don't care, if the variable exists or not. But the question is, where should the `$success` variable come from.

Comment: Thank you for the respose Roman...that's a good question, and one that I wouldn't know how to answer. In the meantime, I have made the change that you suggest, and the error message has gone...thank you kindly. Now I need to check the contact form...fingers crossed.

Comment: I have tested the contact form, and I think that the variable must have been to do with clearing the fields after the form is sent, as the fields do not clear after the success message pops up. I can live with that...thanks again.